# Methods selection for an inherited S4 class

Tags: r, inheritance, methods, r-s4, generic-function

My question is how to apply the generic function `plot()` using my new method for my inherited S4 class.

I extend the existing S4 class (whose name is **stanfit**) in **rstan**, say `lowerS4class`, and define a new method for generic function `plot` for the extended (inherited) S4 class, say `upperS4class`.

But the following  undesired selection (i.e. the selected method is the method 
 for the lower S4 class)  occur with the following `Note` in the R console when I apply the generic function `plot()` for the extended S4 class object `x` as `plot(x)`.

```
Note: method with signature "lowerS4class#missing" chosen for function ‘plot’,
 target signature "upperS4clss#missing".
 "upperS4clss#ANY" would also be valid
```

**Edit** for comment-----------------------------------------

***Inheritance***

```
  setMethod("plot",
           signature(x = "upperS4class"),
           definition = function(x){   
             foo(x)
             }

           )
```

where `foo` is a function defined for upperS4class.

**Def.** for `upperS4class`

```
upperS4class <- setClass(
                  #Name for upper class
                  "upperS4class",

                   # Inheritance
                   contains = "lowerS4class"

                   # New slots
                   representation(

                      .....
                   ),

                   # Initial values for new slots
                   prototype(
                      .....


                      ),

)
```

---Edit for comments------------------

By changing the above as follows, it goes well. Thank you for @JDL.

```
 setMethod("plot",
           signature(x = "stanfitExtended",
                     y = "missing"       # <--------------What's New !!
                     ),
           definition = function(x){ 
             foo(x)
             }

       )
```

Comment: Could you post your method definition (or a skeleton of it)? Is the method defined for signature `x=upperS4class,y=missing` or just `x=upperS4class`? (I am also assuming your class definition starts with `setClass("upperS4class",contains="lowerS4class",...) -> upperS4class`)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am not sure your code `y=missing`. Is it needed ?

Comment: I think it might be — try it and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for @JDL. More precisely `y="missing"` So it helps me very much and learn alot. Thank you !!

Comment: yes, the method definition should start `setMethod("plot",signature(x="upperS4class",y="missing"),...)` . The reason this helps is because then both arguments in the signature match *exactly*, which is what R tries to prioritise with method selection.